# Capistrano: disable db:migrate

Tags: capistrano

How do you disable db:migrate when doing a `cap deploy:cold` with Capistrano?

In config/deploy.rb the only reference to `deploy:migrate` is commented out but it's still attempting to do:

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300592/skip-database-migration-while-deploying-rails-application-using-capistrano-3

Answer (score 4):

I got success by overriding the `deploy:migrate` method in my `config/deploy.rb`.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "No ActiveRecord override"
  task :migrate do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When re-defining a task in Capistrano v2, the original task was replaced. However the Rake DSL on which Capistrano v3 is built is additive. According to [documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/overriding-capistrano-tasks/).
Under most circumstances, you will simply want to use clear_actions, which removes the specified task’s behaviour, but does not alter it’s dependencies or comments:

```
namespace :deploy do
  Rake::Task["migrate"].clear_actions
  task :migrate do
    puts "no migration"
  end
end
```

Comment: The info about the new way of overriding tasks is correct. However the clear_actions line should be Rake::Task["deploy:migrate"]. Otherwise, Capistrano throws an error, can't find "migrate" task.

Furthermore, theres no need to the enclosing namespace block.

You can disable migrations just adding the line Rake::Task["deploy:migrate"].clear_actions in the deploy.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. That's why I override it in the Rakefile. Like this:

```
namespace :db do

  desc "db:migration fakes"
  task :migrate => :environment do
    p 'No. We will not migrate!'
  end

end
```

Here you can add more logic if you like. You could for example trigger a real migration on certain environments.