# Skip database migration while deploying Rails application using Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano3

When we run `cap deploy`, it runs all the migrations during deployment. We have to point the application to existing DB and don't want modify existing DB.

Can anybody suggest how can we skip the migration step while deploying the application?

Comment: Does anyone know a command line way to disable it so you don't have to commit a change to the repo if that is undesirable?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suppose you are using [capistrano/rails](https://github.com/capistrano/rails).

According to the doc, you can require just what you need manually:

```
# Capfile
require 'capistrano/bundler' 
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```